# Keep Illustrator CS5 tool options window open?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs5

In Illustrator, CS5 is there any way to keep the tool options window open or viewable when using the blob brush/eraser tools?  It's a pain in the butt when you havg to change the direction or shape of the brush tip with every stroke!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to keep the dialog box open. Both use a modal dialog, which passes its values back to Illustrator upon closing. Unfortunately, Adobe did not include modeless dialogs (palettes) for these tools in CS5.

You probably already know this, but the standard shortcut for opening a tool's dialog settings is the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button. I find that's the easiest way.

Comment: Hi Alex, please explain. The `Enter` key doesn't open any "Tool dialog setting" for me in Illustrator. Is it a setting I've missed?

Comment: For any tool that has a modal dialog (pencil, brush, eyedropper, shape-builder, etc.), pressing `Enter` should bring it up if that tool is active. Windows and Mac alike.

Comment: Well I'll be, you're right. Guess I never noticed that before.

Comment: I didn't notice myself until I started using Scriptographer heavily. Guess you're one of [today's lucky 10000](http://xkcd.com/1053/)

Answer (score 2):

No. The options can't remain open.

If you're that concerned about the dynamics of the brush you may want to look into getting a Wacom tablet.